# PhpMailer Attachment with Verot class.upload.php resized

Tags: php, image, email, phpmailer, verot-upload-class

I'm using class.upload.php to resize an image from a form and I would like to use the resized image on the fly to send it with phpMailer but my code below is not working ;((

The image is not send !

Without sending a mail the resize image works fine ;))

Thanks for your help...

```
$handle = new upload($_FILES['file']); 
if ($handle->uploaded) {
    //$handle->file_new_name_body   = 'image_resized';
    $handle->image_resize         = true;
    $handle->image_x              = 200;
    $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
    $handle->image_no_enlarging   = true;
    $handle->jpeg_quality         = 50;

    $attach = base64_encode($handle->process());

    $mail->AddAttachment($attach, 'myimage.jpg');
}
```

Comment: image is delivered in original form?

Comment: Yes with multipart/form-data. Everything works fine to resize the image but how can I handle it to pass it to the AddAttachment ?

Comment: Is it woking to send an image without resizing?

Comment: I need to resize the image first ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addAttachment` reads file from local filesystem path, use `addStringAttachment` instead:

```
$mail->addStringAttachment($attach, 'myimage.jpg');
```

PHPMailer docs page: [String Attachments](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial#string-attachments)

Comment: Thanks so much ;)) That works with addStringAttachment. I just had to remove base64_encode